# Images are getting blur after retrieve from database

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, blob

Following is the code to retrieve image from database and then saving it to a folder.

```
public string BinarytoNewsImage(int ID)
        {
            byte[] btimage = null;
            string image = "";
            string filename = null;
            int mediaid;

            DataSet dsNews = new DataSet();
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Top 1 * from tblNew Where intNewId=" + ID, offcon);
            adp.Fill(dsNews, "tblNews1");
            if (dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows[0]["strImage"] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    btimage = (byte[])dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows[0]["strImage"];
                    mediaid = Convert.ToInt32(dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows[0]["intMediaId"].ToString());
                    filename = dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows[0]["strfilename"].ToString();
                    image = BinarytoImage(btimage, mediaid);
                }
                else
                {
                    filename = dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows[0]["strfilename"].ToString();
                    image = "http://www.patrika.com/media/" + filename;
                }
            }

            return image;
        }

        public string BinarytoImage(byte[] stream, int ID)
        {
            string ImagePath = "";
            string Image = ID + ".jpg";

            var URL = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImagePath"].ToString();

            string FolderName = new Uri(URL).LocalPath;

            var help = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(FolderName);

            if (Directory.Exists(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(FolderName)))
            {
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(FolderName), ID + ".jpg");
                if (files.Length > 0)
                {
                    ImagePath = URL + ID + ".jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(stream, 0, stream.Length))
                    {
                        MS.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);

                        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS);

                        img.Save(help + ID + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                        img.Dispose();
                        img = null;
                        ImagePath = URL + ID + ".jpg";
                    }
                }
            }
            return ImagePath;
        }
```

**Everything is working fine the images are saving to a folder but my problem is images are getting blur after retrieval.**

I just don't know the reason as when I am using another code for retrieval than images are coming fine but are not saved to folder:

```
DataSet dsNews = new DataSet();
            adp = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Top 1 * from tblNew Where intNewId=901371", con);
            adp.Fill(dsNews, "tblNews1");

            if (dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows[0]["strImage"] != DBNull.Value)
            {
                byte[] btimage = (byte[])dsNews.Tables["tblNews1"].Rows[0]["strImage"];
                Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                Response.BinaryWrite(btimage);
            }
```

**I need those images to be saved to folder** so that I don't have to call database after once image comes.

Comment: when you step thru the code do you get values for when doing the save..? also you are not wouldn't you also need to call MS.Flush()..? and Response.Flush() after doing the BinaryWrite..?

Comment: Why are you saving them to the folder as GIF when they stored in the Db as JPEG?

Comment: yeah.. just saw that and yes that might be a problem...
so sorry i didn't look at it...
will see again and then let u know...

Comment: Getting this error **"A generic error occurred in GDI+."**

Comment: How sure are you that the images are stored correctly in the Db?

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt: i have tried to get images from another method as i mentioned in my question and getting a very fine image from this..'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it help to change this line

```
    img.Save(help + ID + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

to store it as JPEG rather? as that's the source format

**EDIT:**
Your are not moving the stream pointer back to the start.

Try change these lines:

```
            using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(stream, 0, stream.Length))
                {
                    MS.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);

                    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS);
             ...
```

To

```
            using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(stream, 0, stream.Length))
                {
                    MS.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);
                    MS.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(MS);
```

...

Comment: Getting this error **"A generic error occurred in GDI+."**
when i am converting **System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif**
to **System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg**

Comment: After you write the byte[] to the stream you must reset the stream to seek to the first position before creating the image from the stream

Comment: see my edit.  your problem may be that you're not setting the stream position back to the beginning when you should.

Comment: Also, after the Using clause you're writing the stream (MS) back to the byte array (stream)... this is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

I write the common method, all is ok.
Maybe your byte[]stream is not right,pls check.

```
 byte[] stream = File.ReadAllBytes(@"D:\YWG\123.jpg");
            using (MemoryStream MS = new MemoryStream(stream, 0, stream.Length))
            {
                MS.Write(stream, 0, stream.Length);

                using (Image img = Image.FromStream(MS))
                {
                    img.Save(@"D:\dd.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
                } 
            }
```

I see the dest file "dd.jpg" is ok.